# Why am I getting duplicate ID columns when using Table Per Hierarchy in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use "table per hierarchy" to model a variety of account types in my database using EF Core (2.1) and I am having a problem where I am getting additional foreign key columns added for the derived types. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018833/entity-framework-table-per-hierarchy-inserting-multiple-id-columns) question/answer but I don't think it is the same as my situation.

Here are my account classes:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Standard : Base
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentId))]
    public Elevated Parent { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Elevated : Base
{
    public ICollection<Base> Accounts { get; set; } = new List<Base>();
}

public class Plus : Elevated
{
}

public class Ultimate : Elevated
{
}
```

And I have configured TPH like this in my DbContext constructor:

```
builder.Entity<Base>()
    .HasDiscriminator<string>("Type")
        .HasValue<Ultimate>("ultimate")
        .HasValue<Plus>("plus")
        .HasValue<Standard>("standard");
```

and I seed some basic data like this:

```
builder.Entity<Ultimate>().HasData(new Ultimate() { Id = 1 });
builder.Entity<Plus>().HasData(new Plus() { Id = 2 });
builder.Entity<Standard>().HasData(new Standard() { Id = 3, ParentId = 1 });
```

when I then run migrations I get this table:

[image: my table]

with this data:

[image: my data]

As you can see I have a `ElevatedId` column that I do not want. If I remove the `Accounts` collection from the `Elevated` class I do not get that column; but I need/want that navigation property.

Is there anything I should be doing differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model any Base can be added to the `Accounts` of an Elevated, and so every Base needs and ElevatedId Foreign Key property.  Only a Standard can have an Elevated `Parent`.

And a Standard can have an Elevated `Parent` and belong to the `Accounts` of a *different* Elevated.

Comment: Ah! So is the answer to change the type of `Accounts` from `Base` to `Standard`? Sorry I'm away from my computer until tomorrow now but I can't not know until then!

Comment: Yes that was the answer! Thanks @davidbrowne